# Angularjs scope length outside function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Im a newbie in AngularJs and do not really know how to get length of response outside function.

```
  var onUsers = function(response){               
  $scope.users = response.data;      
  console.log($scope.users.length);  //here works
  }
```

But when i try  outside onUsers function

```
 console.log($scope.users.length);
```

I get an error.

Comment: Do you get anything with `console.log($scope.users)`?

Comment: You're accessing `$scope.users` before it is assigned the `response.data`. `$http` is Promise returning so you need to access the data after the Promise has resolved.

Comment: @peteb yes thats the solution , thanks !

Comment: @Konkko i  couldnt get any data with that line too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to access $scope.users.length before your response has returned from the server. so $scope.users is still undefined. This is a classic problem of asynchronous javascript and you need to use promises for this.
Which means that you should write the code that you are executing outside onUsers in the promise callback.

Read this:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Yes, i was trying to get that before response . Thank you for detailed explanation !

Answer (score 1):

You can use $scope.$watch for run a function when the variable change.

```
$scope.$watch('users', function(users) {
    console.log(users.length);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will take it in consideration .

Answer (score 0):

AS the angular code runs asynchronous so `console.log($scope.users.length)` runs before the promise returned.

```
var onUsers = function(response){               
      $scope.users = response.data;      
      console.log($scope.users.length);  //here works
      }
```

your `console.log($scope.users.length)` in above function works because it is a success handler.
you can get the your console.log works out side the success handler by using `$timeout`. i am assuming after 5000 your response will arive.

```
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log($scope.users.length);
  }, 5000);
```